# R remove duplicate polygons from a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, r-sp

I need to remove duplicate polygons from a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in R. There is a method for points but not for polygons.

I need to do that for creating a tool to similar reshape() for spatial data.

Comment: A reproducible example would do wonders here. How exactly are the polygons duplicated? are they duplicated `Polygons` or duplicated `Polygon`s?

Comment: I mean duplicate as in having the same values for the `@coords` slot in `Polygon`. I'll work up a reproducible example.

Comment: @PhilipGreenwood a reproducible example helps seekers to understand what the problem is and compare it with their problem. An image or an example of your attempt is always useful.

Answer (score 5):

If by duplicated polygons, you mean polygons with identical data, you can use this code:

```
shp <- shapefile("shape.shp")
shp <- shp[!duplicated(shp@data),]
```

---

**EDIT**

If by duplicated polygons, you mean polygons with identical coordinates (`@coords` slot), you can use this code:

```
shp <- shapefile("shape.shp")
coord_poly <- lapply(shp@polygons, function(x){lapply(x@Polygons, function(x){coordinates(x)})}) 
shp <- shp[!duplicated(coord_poly),]
```

Comment: Would be helpful to explain what the nested lapply function is doing. Otherwise its difficult to modify functions.

Answer (score 3):

The answer would depend a bit on what you want to do with the attributes.

Example data:

```
library(raster)   
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
p <- p[1:2, ]
pp <- bind(p,p)
data.frame(pp)

#  ID_1   NAME_1 ID_2   NAME_2 AREA
#1    1 Diekirch    1 Clervaux  312
#2    1 Diekirch    2 Diekirch  218
#3    1 Diekirch    1 Clervaux  312
#4    1 Diekirch    2 Diekirch  218
```

If you want to combine polygons that have the same attributes (but perhaps different geometries), you can use aggregate:

```
a <- aggregate(pp, names(pp))
data.frame(a)

#  ID_1   NAME_1 ID_2   NAME_2 AREA
#1    1 Diekirch    1 Clervaux  312
#2    1 Diekirch    2 Diekirch  218
```

If you know they are duplicates in geometry and attributes, you can use @DJack's solution:

```
b <- pp[!duplicated(data.frame(pp)),]
```

If it is just the areas you care about, you could do

```
d <- union(pp)
```

And you could reconstitute the attributes with the info in

```
data.frame(d)
#     ID.1 ID.2 ID.3 ID.4 count
#1    1    0    1    0     2
#2    0    1    0    1     2
```

But in that case, it would be simpler to do:

```
g <- geom(pp)
x <- split(g[,c(2, 4:6)], g[,1])
dd <- duplicated(x)
dd
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Followed by

```
z <- pp[!dd, ]
```

Package `terra` has a `unique` method for `SpatVector` objects:

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(pp)
u <- unique(pp)
u

# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : polygons 
# dimensions  : 2, 5  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 5.826232, 6.315773, 49.78479, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# names       :  ID_1   NAME_1  ID_2   NAME_2  AREA
# type        : <num>    <chr> <num>    <chr> <num>
# values      :     1 Diekirch     1 Diekirch   312
#                   1 Diekirch     2 Diekirch   218
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `rgeos::gEquals(x, byid = TRUE)` with `x` the object with the polygons.

Comment: Hmm. Good point but it's actually pretty hard to implement this deletion from a given matrix or list. Should I waste so many time to do this? Any simple recipe?